# How to store numbers in malloc array?

Tags: c

I want to use the count variable to store numbers in the W array using malloc, but the output keeps repeating the same number entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int *w = malloc( sizeof(int) * 10000);

  int x; int count = 0;                                                                             
  while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
      printf("%d", &x]);
      *(w +  x) = count;
      count++;

    }

  free(w); w = NULL;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `*(w + count) = x;`? `w[count] = x` is the more traditional syntax. You also want `printf("%d", x]);` since you're printing a value and not a pointer. It wouldn't matter if the way you're storing them in the array is incorrect since you're never using the array when printing.

Comment: Considering that the code you show won't build, I don't think that it prints anything at all. Please make sure you have a proper [mre] to show us. And copy-paste it into the question instead of (re)writing the code.

Comment: Before posting code that is supposed to reproduce the problem, please verify that the code actually reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. `argc`, `argv` are not used so leave them out.
2. Prefer `sizeof` a variable (`*w`) opposed to a type (`int`).  If the type changes you only need to make the change in one place.
3. Use constants instead of magic values.
4. You don't need the temporary variable `x`.
5. Prefer unsigned (`size_t`) types to (unsigned) int for values that should not be negative.  It eliminates a possible error class.
6. Prefer a `for` to `while`-loop when counting things.  It might be more readable like this:

```
    for(size_t count = 0;; count++) {
        if(scanf("%d", &w[count]) != 1)
            break;
        printf("%d\n", w[count]);
    }
```

7. `printf("%d", ...)` takes a value not an address.  This appears to be the main issue.
8. For readability by user add a new newline when printing the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 10000

int main() {
    int *w = malloc(LEN * sizeof *w);
    for(size_t count = 0; scanf("%d", &w[count]) == 1; count++)
        printf("%d\n", w[count]);
    free(w);
}
```

example session:

```
$ ./a.out 
1
1
2
2
4
4
```

Comment: After `for(size_t count = 0;; count++) { if(scanf("%d", &w[count]) != 1) break; printf("%d\n", w[count]);  }`, `count` is lost.  Not so important here, but likely needed in larger code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Indeed.  Let's just leave your comment as documentation.  The fix is move the `size_t count = 0;` declaration outside the loop (or whatever scope needs access to it).